# Can't find C++ 6.0 IDE in MSDN download area

Tags: c++

I think this has something to do with a lawsuit with Sun over Java - but I can't verify this.  I'm trying to get a legacy code base to compile 1st so I can begin upgrading it.

Also: I suppose I need to know where/how I CAN get the C++ 6.0 IDE install.

Digging through the "Pile of DVD's in the old developer's drawer" right now.

Comment: You're probably right about the Java - that's why they withdrew the Office 2000 downloads IIRC - but it is also out of support life. I'm sure loads of us have it but aren't really allowed to just give it to you.

Comment: http://www.itwriting.com/blog/167-visual-studio-6-on-vista.html states the official reason is the Java issue.

Comment: You had to know the day was coming when it would no longer be possible to use VC6.  Porting your app in 2005 may have seemed like an academic waste of effort & time back then.  But I bet you won't make the same mistake twice. :)

Comment: There's always the pirate bay if you can't find the CD/DVD. I'm not sure it would be breaking any laws. You have the right to use it, due to your MSDN subscription. Microsoft does not have the right to distribute it due to a settlement. Maybe it's a win-win? I'm not a lawyer, nor do I pretend to be one, so add salt as necessary...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this was a result of the 2001 settlement between Microsoft and Sun over the Microsoft Java Virtual Machine.  Several products were axed because of this, including Windows 98, Windows Me, Office 2000, Office XP, IE 5.5

Best place to find a license is at an auction site.  It was always available at Ebay for example, prices have been steadily climbing.

Comment: Thanks - I ended up finding the CDs in a box under the desk.